# Replace last field with previous one

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file that look like this one:

```
10-04-2022 00:39:13,36707,1455008753,32
11-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555008753,26
21-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555408753,15
12-06-2022 00:39:13,36709,1655008753
```

Because values into last field are related to running time of next line, I would like to shift down them to this way for using with gnuplot.

```
10-04-2022 00:39:13,36707,1455008753,
11-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555008753,32
21-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555408753,26
12-06-2022 00:39:13,36709,1655008753,15
```

Answer (score 12):

A simple awk script could do this:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} { tmp=$NF; $NF=save; print; save=tmp; }' < input > output
```

This saves the fourth field into a temporary variable, replaces the fourth field with the previously-saved value, then prints the new line. Once printed, it saves the previous value of that fourth field for the next iteration. On the first line, the "save"d value is empty (the default awk behavior), which achieves the desired result.

The "BEGIN" section sets the Field Separator (used for splitting the input) and the Output Field Separator (used when printing the line/fields back out) to a comma. See your local `awk` man page, various online references, or the [Open Group Base Specifications for awk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 9):

Another `awk` solution, tested on GNU `awk` 5.1.0.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,x;x=$NF}' myfile
10-04-2022 00:39:13,36707,1455008753,
11-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555008753,32
21-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555408753,26
12-06-2022 00:39:13,36709,1655008753,15
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.split(","); my $m = @a>>.elems.max;  \
         .flat.join(",").put for [Z] @a>>.[0..$m-2], ("", @a>>.[$m-1]).flat;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines.map: *.split(","); my $m = @a.map(*.elems).max;  \
         .flat.join(",").put for [Z] @a.map(*.[0..$m-2]), ("", @a.map: *.[$m-1]).flat;'
```

This Raku answer is a little longer but is also more of a general solution, since the number of columns per row isn't hard-coded: a file-wide `max` is computed.

Briefly (both examples), `lines` are read-in, each `split` on `,` commas, and stored in `@a` array. A `max` number of `elems` (columns) is computed and stored as `$m`. Then Raku's `[Z]` "Zip Reduction" operator is used to pull off elements from the two lists that follow it one-by-one: these elements are `flat`tened and `join`ed back together in the out`put`, such that now a `""` empty string occupies the end of the first row, and subsequent `@a[$m-1]` indexed-values are moved down a row. *Nota bene:* Raku doesn't auto-flatten array elements, so you have to `flat`ten them manually (if desired).

In the two examples I've tried to show how Raku's `>>` "hyper"-operator is similar to `map`ping a function/index over individual elements, either `.map(*.fn)` or (at the end of a method chain) using the colon form `.map: *.fn;`, which can reduce the number of parens required.

Sample Input:

```
10-04-2022 00:39:13,36707,1455008753,32
11-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555008753,26
21-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555408753,15
12-06-2022 00:39:13,36709,1655008753
```

Sample Output:

```
10-04-2022 00:39:13,36707,1455008753,
11-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555008753,32
21-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555408753,26
12-06-2022 00:39:13,36709,1655008753,15
```

---

Addendum: Here's another Raku approach, this time unwrapping the row/columns into individual elements, and reconstructing with `rotor`. It gives the exact same result as above:

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.split(",").flat; my @b = @a[3,7,11...*];  \
         @a.=rotor(3 => 1); @a.=map(*.join(",")); @b.=unshift(""); \
        .join(",").put for [Z] @a, @b;'
```

[https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-[]_(reduction_metaoperators)](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-%5B%5D_(reduction_metaoperators))
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-hyper_method_call_operator
https://docs.raku.org/routine/flat

Comment: Nice! Does raku have perl5's `-a` option for auto splitting?

Comment: Thank you @terdon! Not that I am aware of. Raku implements two functions that are supposed to obviate reliance on command-line switches: `comb` and `words`. AFAIK both these have method `fn()`and routine `.fn` forms. The `comb` function takes a regex matcher, and breaks textual input ***around*** any matches. The `words` function breaks on `\s` whitespace, and is conceptually similar to Raku's `lines` function, breaking on `\n` newlines. Actually, it's probably better to say that `.words` is really `.comb(/ \S+ /)` and `.lines` is really `.comb(/ ^^ \N* /)` (copied directly out of the docs).

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed 's extended regex mode to simplify regex composing, our approach is to maintain two lines at any time in the pattern space. Then move previous line's second last field to the current line end.

```bash
sed -E '
  1s/$/,/
  $!N
  s/(,[^,]+)(,[^,]*\n.*)/\2\1/
  P;D
' file
```

---

Input:-

```
10-04-2022 00:39:13,36707,1455008753,32
11-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555008753,26
21-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555408753,15
12-06-2022 00:39:13,36709,1655008753#
```

---

Output:-

```
10-04-2022 00:39:13,36707,1455008753,
11-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555008753,32
21-05-2022 00:39:13,36708,1555408753,26
12-06-2022 00:39:13,36709,1655008753#,15
```

---

Comment: "second to last" --> "last"? and is there an extra `#` in the output, or was that part of your input? (it wasn't in the Question, so I wasn't sure)

Comment: The # I put at my end for testing the last line.

Comment: But it is the second to last of previous line.  You have to look carefully.

Comment: This may just be a language/translation issue, but my clarification is that we're not moving the previous line's "second (to) last field" but rather that line's "last field".